# Checkbox not closing paragraph

Tags: jquery

I can't figure it out why is this not working:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        if ($('#check').is(':checked')) {
            $('p').hide(); 
        } else {
            $('p').show(); 
        }
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="checkbox" id="check" />
    <p>If you click on the checkbox, I will disappear.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d7d2n0x4/1/)

When i click on the checkbox it should hide the p tag but it doesn't...
This should be so simple, but then again it is not :(

Comment: You're only running your code on load of the page. You need to add a `change` event handler to your checkbox

Comment: You are missing onclick action

Comment: aaah you are right...can you make an answer so i can accept it

Comment: @lewis4u no problem, answer added for you

Comment: i need to wait 10 min to accept it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're only running your code on load of the page. You need to add a `change` event handler to your checkbox. Also note that you can simplify the code by passing the `checked` property value to the `toggle()` method:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#check').change(function() {
    $('p').toggle(!this.checked);
  }).change();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="check" />
<p>If you click on the checkbox, I will disappear.</p>
```

Comment: Rory i have a problem now...when i click the checkbox and try to submit the form and if there were any errors my page will reload and the checkbox condition will be changed....is there a way to make the checkbox remember the state? Or should i make a new question for this on SO

Comment: You need to store the state of the checkbox somewhere, either `localStorage`, `sessionStorage`, a cookie, server side session, or a backend database. There should be a few questions on this already if you search. Feel free to ask a new question about it, but please include your attempt.

Comment: Use `localStorage`

Comment: I am using Laravel so the plain html tag `<input type="checkbox"...` doesn't save the old value i just needed to change it to this `{!! Form::checkbox('check', "Ja", null, ['id' => 'check']) !!}` and all is working now...thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

I updated your jsfiddle to work & makes use of the jquery .change function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#check').change(function() {
        if ($('#check').is(':checked')) {
            $('p').css("display","none"); 
        }
        else {
            $('p').css("display","block");
        }
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/d7d2n0x4/2/

Comment: thank you, but Rory has made it very nice and clean so i will accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try it
//  for protect global scope use closure
(function ($) {
  // document ready
  $(function(){
     // use prop method for checkbox
     if ( $('#check').prop( "checked" ) ) {
       $('p').slideToggle(250);
     }
  });
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: Page will loads faster if place code to the page bottom, script start run when DOM is ready.